# Can't run the basic command in ggsunburst. SyntaxError

Tags: python, r

I've just installed ggsunburst package so that I can display labels and percentages in my sunburst figures (`sunburstR` can't do that).
But the very first [example command](https://github.com/didacs/ggsunburst) for ggsunburst gives an error. Could anyone help me, please?

First, `sunburst_data(nw)` prompted me with:

> No non-system installation of Python could be found.
>   Would you like to download and install Miniconda?

So I installed it and the command resulted in:

> nw <- "(((a, b, c), (d, e, f, g)), (f, i, h));"
>   sb <- sunburst_data(nw)
>   Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
>     SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 31)

It looks like python error, but I am R user. Anyway, I have Python 2.7.16 installed, the downloaded Miniconda has python 3.x build.
Before getting ggsunburst I reinstalled R 4.0.0, RTools, I updated reticulate, ggplot2 packages and RStudio. I use Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother helped me eventually :) missing numpy seems to be the issue. This worked:

1. Remove all the miniconda files (I had them in User/ntb/AppData/r-miniconda)
2. Install [numpy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWn8Wj69Dm4)
3. Restart R